# Evaluating $ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \int_0^{x} f(g(x, y, s), s)\ ds $

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let's say we have two sufficiently regular functions $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} : (x,y) \mapsto f(x,y)$ and $g : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R} : (x,y,z) \mapsto g(x,y,z)$ so that we can define

$$ u(x,y) = \int_0^{x} f(g(x, y, s), s)\ ds $$

and differentiate $u$ with respect to $x$.

> How could we evaluate $ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}? $

I tried to use Leibniz integral rule as following:

Take $ h(x, y, s) = f(g(x, y, s), s) $. Then $ u(x,y) = \int_0^{x} h(x, y, s)\ ds $.

So

$$ \partial_x u(a, b) = \partial_1 \int_0^{a} h(a, b, s)\ ds = h(a, b, a) + \int_0^{a} \partial_x h(a, b, s)\ ds $$

Substituting $f$ back

$$ \begin{align}
\partial_x u(a, b) &= f(g(a, b, a), a) + \int_0^{a} \partial_x [ f(g(a, b, s), s) ]\ ds \\
&= f(g(a, b, a), a) + \int_0^{a} \partial_x f(g(a, b, s), s) \ \partial_x g(a, b, s) \ ds
\end{align} $$

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{h}[u(x+h,y)-u(x,y)]&=\dfrac{1}{h}\left[\int_{0}^{x+h}f(g(x+h,y,s),s)ds-\int_{0}^{x}f(g(x+h,y,s),s)ds\right]\\
&~~~~+\dfrac{1}{h}\left[\int_{0}^{x}f(g(x+h,y,s),s)ds-\int_{0}^{x}f(g(x,y,s),s)ds\right]\\
&=\dfrac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h}f(g(x+h,y,s),s)ds\\
&~~~~+\dfrac{1}{h}\int_{0}^{x}\left[f(g(x+h,y,s),s)-f(g(x,y,s),s)\right]ds\\
&\rightarrow f(g(x,y,x),x)+\int_{0}^{x}\partial_{1}f(g(x,y,s),s)\cdot\partial_{1}g(x,y,s)ds
\end{align*}
if all the nice conditions are met.

Note that 
\begin{align*}
&\int_{0}^{x+h}f(g(x+h,y,s),s)ds-\int_{0}^{x}f(g(x+h,y,s),s)ds\\
&=\int_{0}^{x}f(g(x+h,y,s),s)ds+\int_{x}^{x+h}f(g(x+h,y,s),s)ds-\int_{0}^{x}f(g(x+h,y,s),s)ds\\
&=\int_{x}^{x+h}f(g(x+h,y,s),s)ds\\
&=hf(g(x+h,y,\xi_{x,h}),\xi_{x,h}),
\end{align*}
by Mean Value Theorem (integral version), where $\xi_{x,h}$ is in between $x$ and $x+h$, so when $h\rightarrow 0$ and nice conditions are fulfilled, then $f(g(x+h,y,\xi_{x,h}),\xi_{x,h})\rightarrow f(g(x,y,x),x)$.

Comment: What happened to the second term at the right hand side of the first equality?

Comment: Are you saying that $\dfrac{1}{h}\left[\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}f(g(x+h,y,s),s)ds-\int_{0}^{x}f(g(x,y,s),s)ds\right]$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $-\int_{0}^{x}f(g(x+h,y,s),s)ds$

Comment: I have added some more details.